# Nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I am very much new to this JSON objects. So I need some helps from you guys. I have to create a JSON object and that object has two children. One child has some children. If my question is confusing just refer the following diagram. It is similar to nested lists.
Example:

PRODUCT_LIST

```
<ul>
    <li>CATEGORY_ID - A</li>
    <li>PRODUCT_DETAILS
        <ul>
            <li>PRODUCT_ID - A.1</li>
            <li>PRODUCT_NAME - AAAA1111</li>
            <li>UNIT_COST - 0.1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>CATEGORY_ID - B</li>
    <li>PRODUCT_DETAILS
        <ul>
            <li>PRODUCT_ID - B.1</li>
            <li>PRODUCT_NAME - BBBBB1111</li>
            <li>UNIT_COST - 0.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to do but got JavaScript errors. Can any one please help to create JSON for the above mentioned diagram. 
Note: One Category has more than one product details. It means PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME and UNIT_COST will be repeating to more than one time for a particular CATEGORY_ID.

The JavaScript code I have tried

```
var product =   '{"products_list":' +
                '[' + 
                    '{' + 
                        '{"category_id":"A"},' +
                        '{"product_details":' + 
                            '[' + 
                                '{"product_id":"A.1","product_name":"AAAA1111", "unit_cost":"A1"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.2","product_name":"AAAA2222", "unit_cost":"A2"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.3","product_name":"AAAA3333", "unit_cost":"A3"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.4","product_name":"AAAA4444", "unit_cost":"A4"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.5","product_name":"AAAA5555", "unit_cost":"A5"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.6","product_name":"AAAA6666", "unit_cost":"A6"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.7","product_name":"AAAA7777", "unit_cost":"A7"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.8","product_name":"AAAA8888", "unit_cost":"A8"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.9","product_name":"AAAA9999", "unit_cost":"A9"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.0","product_name":"AAAA0000", "unit_cost":"A0"}' +
                            ']' + 
                        '}' + 
                    '},' + 
                    '{' + 
                        '{"category_id":"A"},' +
                        '{"product_details":' + 
                            '[' + 
                                '{"product_id":"A.1","product_name":"AAAA1111", "unit_cost":"A1"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.2","product_name":"AAAA2222", "unit_cost":"A2"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.3","product_name":"AAAA3333", "unit_cost":"A3"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.4","product_name":"AAAA4444", "unit_cost":"A4"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.5","product_name":"AAAA5555", "unit_cost":"A5"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.6","product_name":"AAAA6666", "unit_cost":"A6"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.7","product_name":"AAAA7777", "unit_cost":"A7"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.8","product_name":"AAAA8888", "unit_cost":"A8"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.9","product_name":"AAAA9999", "unit_cost":"A9"},' +
                                '{"product_id":"A.0","product_name":"AAAA0000", "unit_cost":"A0"}' +
                            ']' + 
                        '}' + 
                    '}' + 
                ']' + 
            '}';
```

Comment: Please show us your JavaScript, not some HTML list.

Comment: Please refer my updated question with the Javascript I have tried.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a string containing JSON instead of just an object literal? Don't make it unnecessarily difficult for yourself.

Comment: Yes reason. It is similar to normalization. our customer does not need to use database, instead needs to store in JSON.to avoid the repeat values I tried. Just look the code. 
var product = '{"products_list":[' +
'{"category_id":"A","product_id":"A.1","product_name":"AAAA1111", "unit_cost":"A1"},' +
'{"category_id":"A","product_id":"A.2","product_name":"AAAA2222", "unit_cost":"A2"},' +
'{"category_id":"B","product_id":"B.1","product_name":"BBBB1111", "unit_cost":"B1"},' +
'{"category_id":"B","product_id":"B.6","product_name":"BBBB6666", "unit_cost":"B6"}]}';
To avoid category repeating..

Comment: Thanks for the efforts given for my questions. I have got the answer from "Bergi".. :)

Comment: Remember to tick Bergi's answer as accepted so he gets the lovely green tick ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the HTML tree, you will get the followin JSON representation for the PRODUCT_LIST:

```
[
   {
      "CATEGORY_ID":"A",
      "PRODUCT_DETAILS":[
         {
            "PRODUCT_ID":"A.1",
            "PRODUCT_NAME":"AAAA1111",
            "UNIT_COST":0.1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "CATEGORY_ID":"B",
      "PRODUCT_DETAILS":[
         {
            "PRODUCT_ID":"B.1",
            "PRODUCT_NAME":"BBBBB1111",
            "UNIT_COST":0.2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

---

However, your JavaScript produces a nearly valid JSON *string*, which is assigned to the `product` variable. You could use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on it, but that's too complicated. As the [JavaScriptObjectNotation](http://json.org) is a subset of the Javascript [object *literal* syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2C_variables%2C_and_literals#Object_literals), you should directly assign the object.

In your JSON, you have some braces too much around the category objects. You can check that e.g. with http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. Corrected script:

```
var product = {
   "products_list":[
      {
         "category_id":"A",
         "product_details":[
            {
               "product_id":"A.1",
               "product_name":"AAAA1111",
               "unit_cost":"A1"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.2",
               "product_name":"AAAA2222",
               "unit_cost":"A2"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.3",
               "product_name":"AAAA3333",
               "unit_cost":"A3"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.4",
               "product_name":"AAAA4444",
               "unit_cost":"A4"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.5",
               "product_name":"AAAA5555",
               "unit_cost":"A5"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.6",
               "product_name":"AAAA6666",
               "unit_cost":"A6"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.7",
               "product_name":"AAAA7777",
               "unit_cost":"A7"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.8",
               "product_name":"AAAA8888",
               "unit_cost":"A8"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.9",
               "product_name":"AAAA9999",
               "unit_cost":"A9"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.0",
               "product_name":"AAAA0000",
               "unit_cost":"A0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "category_id":"A",
         "product_details":[
            {
               "product_id":"A.1",
               "product_name":"AAAA1111",
               "unit_cost":"A1"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.2",
               "product_name":"AAAA2222",
               "unit_cost":"A2"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.3",
               "product_name":"AAAA3333",
               "unit_cost":"A3"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.4",
               "product_name":"AAAA4444",
               "unit_cost":"A4"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.5",
               "product_name":"AAAA5555",
               "unit_cost":"A5"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.6",
               "product_name":"AAAA6666",
               "unit_cost":"A6"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.7",
               "product_name":"AAAA7777",
               "unit_cost":"A7"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.8",
               "product_name":"AAAA8888",
               "unit_cost":"A8"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.9",
               "product_name":"AAAA9999",
               "unit_cost":"A9"
            },
            {
               "product_id":"A.0",
               "product_name":"AAAA0000",
               "unit_cost":"A0"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All identifiers should be in quotes.
By indexing by category id and making the categories arrays of objects I think you get all the features and capabilities of your data structure and make the solution very flexible.

```
var category = {
  "A": [
    { "product_id": "A.1", "product_name": "AAAA1111", "unit_cost": 0.1 },
    { "product_id": "A.2", "product_name": "AAAA2222", "unit_cost": 0.2 },
  ],
  "B": [
    { "product_id": "B.1", "product_name": "BBBB1111", "unit_cost": 0.2 },
    { "product_id": "B.2", "product_name": "BBBB2222", "unit_cost": 0.4 },
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts given for my questions. I have got the answer from "Bergi".. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a confusing question, but I'd probably have JSON something like this

```
var data = [
  {
    category_id: 'A',
    product_id: 'A.1',
    product_name: 'AAAA1111',
    unit_cost: 0.1
  },
  {
    category_id: 'B',
    product_id: 'B.1',
    product_name: 'BBBB1111',
    unit_cost: 0.2
  }
];
```

And then filter it by category when displaying. You might find http://underscorejs.org/ useful for filtering your results

Comment: He seems to be asking about general object syntax in JS from the notes on the question

Comment: Thanks for the efforts given for my questions. I have got the answer from "Bergi".. :)